# Boolean value of proposition assuming previous boolean values of parts of the proposition

Tags: logic

Is it possible to ask *Mathematica* to give us the boolean value of a proposition assuming the boolean value of some parts of it?

For instance, give the boolean value of $p\vee q$ assuming that $p$ is true and $q$ is false.

Comment: `Simplify[Or[p, q], Not[q]]` outputs `p`, for instance. `Simplify[Or[p, q], p && Not[q]]` outputs True.

Comment: Patrick, Why don't you post your comment as a response?  I wasn't aware that  `Simplify` could make boolean inferences.

Comment: `Simplify[Or[p, q], p && ! q]` yields `True`. In fact it was stated in this post [Solve for when two symbolic complex numbers are equal](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/94700/solve-for-when-two-symbolic-complex-numbers-are-equal/94705#94705)

Comment: But when you input something like `Simplify[And[p,q], p && Not[q]]` it outputs `q`, it's not really doing the right thing, because I know, and I wanted _Mathematica_ to know, that `q` is false, I believe it's not clear in that instruction that that is a fact.

Comment: @Concept7 OK, what about `Simplify[And[p, q], Not[q]]`, which returns `False`?

Comment: @PatrickStevens but in that case we wouldn't give the information that `p`is true. Is there a way to give more than one assumption?

Comment: @Concept7 Yes. `Simplify[expr, p && Not[q]]`. I don't understand your question.

Comment: @PatrickStevens I want to say that `p` is true and `q` is false, aren't you assuming only `p && Not[q]`, I mean aren't you assuming something about the conjunction instead of the atomic propositions?

Comment: @Concept7 $p$ is true and $q$ false iff $p \wedge \neg q$.

Comment: Yes, that works for $\wedge$ for doesn't work every time. For instance: Assuming that $p\Rightarrow q$ is true, what's the boolean value of $(p\vee r)\Rightarrow (q\vee r)$? Is there a simple method of solving this in Mathematica?

Comment: I suddenly stopped understanding, why `Simplify[Or[p, q], Not[q]]` gives `p`, but `Simplify[Or[p,q], Not[q] == True]` gives `Or[p, q]`... I like this approach though: `With[{q = True}, And[p, q]]`

Answer (score 3):

`Simplify` handles this.

```
Simplify[And[p, q], Not[q]]
```

returns `False`.

```
Simplify[And[p, q], q]
```

returns `p`.

Answer (score 2):

You can use `BooleanTable` or simply rule replace:

```
TableForm[BooleanTable[{p, q, Or[p, q]}], 
 TableHeadings -> {None, {"p", "q", "p \[Or] q"}}]
```

[image]

```
p \[Or] q /. {p -> True, q -> False}
```

yields `True`

Some other examples:

```
ex1 = a \[Or] b /. {a -> True, b -> False}
ex2 = ex1 && c /. {c -> True}
ex3 = ex1 \[Implies] d /. {d -> False}
```

yielding `True`,`True`, `False` respectively.